# MySql Workbench error 1452 cannot add or update a child row a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql

Here is my table and I keep getting this error. Everything is good to go until I execute the  code that I have put in bold at the bottom. Im really close to completing this table but ive tried everything to solve this error but it keeps coming up.

Please Help me

Thank You`

UPDATE

I took your guys suggestions and changed the inserted data now im getting an error 1136 which is column doesnt match value count for row 1 which is visit ID so its a datatype problem but ive tried everything and I cant figure it out IM SO CLOSE TO BEING DONE

PLEASE HELP!

```
Create Schema Visit;


create table roomtableS(
RoomID char (2)     not null,
RoomNum char (2)    not null,
Charge integer not null,
CONSTRAINT RoomTable_PK Primary Key(RoomID));


Insert into roomtableS values
('01','1A',125.00),
('02','1A',150.00),
('03','1A',100.00),
('04','1A',200.00),
('05','2B',150.00),
('06','2B',125.00),
('07','3C',200.00),
('08','3C',125.00),
('09','3C',100.00);





SELECT * FROM ROOMTABLES;


create table PATIENT(
PatientID    char(5)    not null, 
PatientName  Char(25) not null, 
PatientEmail     Char(30) null,
PatientPhoneNumber Char(10) null,
PatientAddress    Char(100) null,
constraint PATIENT_PK Primary key(PatientID));

insert PATIENT values
('P1', 'Bruce Willis', 'bwillis@mail.org', '2022223333', '1111 Cosmic dr'),
('P2', 'Demi Moore', 'moore@email.net', '2021113333', '1112 Cosmic dr'),
('P3', 'Andre Agassi', 'agassi@mail.org', '2023333333', '1113 Cosmic dr'),
('P4', 'Jet Lee', 'jetlee@email.net', '2023334444', '1114 Chinatown ct'),
('P5', 'Jim Carey', 'carey@email.net', '2023335555', '1115 United dr'),
('P6', 'Bruce Lee', 'bruce@gmail.com', '2023336666', '1115 Chinatown ct');

select* From PATIENT;




Create table SERVICETable(
ServiceID       Char (5) not null,
ServiceTreatment Char(25) not null,
ServiceCost     numeric  not null,
constraint  SERVICE_PK Primary Key(ServiceID));

insert SERVICETable values
('S1','Sore throat', 10.00),
('S2', 'Fever', 15.00),
('S3', 'Headache', 10.00),
('S4', 'Blood pressusre', 20.00),
('S5', 'Yearly checkup', 30.00),
('S6', 'Common cold', 15.00);

select* from SERVICETable;


Create Table doctortable(
DocID char (5)   NOT NULL,
DoctorFirstName char(15) Not NULL,
DoctorLastName char (15) Not Null,
DoctorPhone char (15) Not Null,
CONSTRAINT DoctorTable_PK Primary Key(DocID));


INSERT INTO doctortable values
('D1','Tim','Edward','555-123-4567'),
('D2','Andy','Smith','888-777-6666'),
('D3','John','Smith','222-321-7654');






Select * From doctortable;



Create Table visit(
VisitID char (2) not Null,
PatientID Char (5) not null,
DocID Char (5) not null,
ServiceID Char (5)  not Null,
RoomID char (2) not Null,
Visit date  not null,
CONSTRAINT   VISIT_PK    PRIMARY KEY (VisitID));



Alter table Visit 
add foreign key (PatientID)
references Patient (PatientID);


Alter table Visit 
add foreign key (DocID)
references doctortable (DocID);

Alter table Visit 
add foreign key (ServiceID)
references ServiceTable (ServiceID);

Alter table Visit 
add foreign key (RoomID)
references roomtableS (RoomID);


Insert into Visit (VisitID,RoomID,ServiceID,PatientID,Visit) values
**('1','P1','D1','S1','05','2014-01-03'),
('2','P2','D2','S2','01','2014-01-10'),
('3','P3','D1','S3','02','2014-01-10'),
('4','P4','D2','S4','07','2014-01-15'),
('5','P1','D3','S2','08','2014-01-10'),
('6','P5','D3','S5','03','2014-02-02'),
('7','P4','D1','S6','06','2014-01-10'),
('8','P3','D2','S5','03','2014-02-03'),
('9','P2','D3','S6','01','2014-02-04'),
('10','P3','D1','S2','06','2014-02-04'),
('11','P5','D2','S4','04','2014-02-05'),
('12','P4','D1','S5','09','2014-02-06');**
Select * from Visit;
```

Thank You!

Comment: you forgot INTO --> INSERT INTO Visit VALUES...

Comment: still gives me the same error

Comment: @ôkio: `INTO` is optional. But better to use for cross platform compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert query into `Visit` table is like this:

```
Insert Visit Values
('1','P1','D1','S1','2B','2014-01-03'),
```

Values are expected to be in the order of

```
(VisitID, RoomID, ServiceID, PatientID, DocID, Visit)
```

But they seem to be in a different order.

Change the `insert` statement to include *column names*.

```
Insert Visit 
(VisitID, PatientID, DocID, ServiceID, RoomID, Visit) 
Values
('1','P1','D1','S1','2B','2014-01-03'),
```

And the values, `'2B'` being inserted into `'RoomID'` column seem to be `'RoomNum'` values but not `'RoomID'` values. Change it to `'05'`, or `'06'`. Such change has to be done in all other inputs for the column.

Comment: I did what you told me but now im getting error 1136 which says the column count doesnt match count at row 1 which is visit ID so its something with the data type but ive tried everything and I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Look at my `Insert` statement suggested. It has correct number of columns to match input number of columns. Yours might be missing somewhere. Post it.